# My ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC website does not work on Linux

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, nginx, .net-core, kestrel

My web app works fine in my local Windows machine in the Visual Studio 2019 debugger, and it used to work fine in my remote Linux server too, behind an Nginx reverse-proxy. Lately, I've ported it to .NET Core 3.1, made the necessary changes, and now it only works in my local machine, while in my remote machine it outputs the normal stuff as if it were working, however, it just doesn't respond to browsers.

This is my startup code:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log("Initializing Kestrel Web Server...");
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
        }
    }
```

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            Log("Kestrel Web Server Initialized");
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddOptions();

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
                
            });
            
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
            
            services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            //if (env.IsDevelopment())
            //    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            //else

            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/Index");
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions { ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto });
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseClientId(); // ClientIdMiddleware.cs - custom middleware
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                //
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("id", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("user", "{controller=User}/{username}/{action=Profile}");
            });
        }
    }
```

When I start my app on Linux, I only get:

```
Initializing Kestrel Web Server...
Kestrel Web Server Initialized
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /opt/website/home
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

While the client (browser) initially appears to be loading the page for like 10 seconds, then ends up showing the ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Probably a long shot. Have you tried a boilerplate .net core 3.1 template on your Linux box?

Comment: I didn't try. Now I tried creating an empty project and a placeholder page. Oddly, I'm having the same exact result. Could it be an Nginx configuration issue? However, I didn't touch it since it was working.

Comment: it seems to have to do with your environment - maybe check nginx config as well as firewall/SELinux state?

Comment: It's totally weird and nonsense to me, but I change the port from 5000/5001 to 5005/5006 and now it appears to be working, however, the page loads in a slow manner, and the styles/bootstrap appear to be bugged.

Comment: That may be related to your SSL cert for local machine. you may need to run `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` in your local machine before running the app via HTTPS. [This post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DevelopingLocallyWithASPNETCoreUnderHTTPSSSLAndSelfSignedCerts.aspx) explains what's going on.

Comment: Hi, in my local (development) Windows machine everything works fine, and I'm not getting any SSL error. My problem is now that in my Linux (production) machine, the website is not being displayed like it should.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the issue; it was case sensitivity: I was referencing my stylesheet as 'Main.css', but it actually was named 'main.css'. This solves the second problem, however it doesn't explain the main problem, whose workaround was to change ports, thus I will leave the question open.